# How do I turn on battery percentage in Android Lollipop?

Tags: battery, 5.0-lollipop

I haven't been able to find a menu option for this setting in Android Lollipop (previously known as Android-L).

Answer (score 5):

This website has a good page on the information:

http://nexus7.wonderhowto.com/how-to/unlock-android-ls-hidden-battery-percentage-icon-status-bar-0155876/

But if you want a quick and dirty way to enable this, you can just use:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:status_bar_show_battery_percent --bind value:i:1
```

followed by

```
adb reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:status_bar_show_battery_percent --bind value:i:1
adb reboot
```

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of [Battery percent for Kitkat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kroegerama.android4batpercent) (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: its make thing to user to identify easily with pictures. its having here and settings on which screen would be important so added with the picture nothing more i did here! thanks for respose @Andrew T.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean the answer was bad. The image definitely helped, but readers might be confused since inputting the `adb` command won't show the image. Instead, I remember that the image is from [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kroegerama.android4batpercent) app. Friendly suggestion to add the link to the app on your answer, this way it becomes more useful :)

Comment: It's not a good habit to just post some code without explanation. Where to run that code? Not everyone is familiar with ADB. And even if one knows the name, would he be willing to install the entire SDK for that (though that's not strictly required, it's the first people think of)? What about running it in terminal instead (omitting the `adb shell` prefix)? This could be a great answer if you would make it such. So feel encouraged to [edit] your post and improve it :)